# MSTest.exe not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest

In Windows sever where VS2013 not installed, i tried to run MsTest.exe.

```
MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\Sources\Nerddinner_3.0\CodeCoverage.testrunconfig" /searchpathroot:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\Binaries" /resultsfileroot:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\TestResults" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\Binaries\NerdDinner.Tests.dll"
```

Im getting the output. When i tried to publish the report, Im facing below mentioned error.

**MSTest:**

```
MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\Sources\Nerddinner_3.0\CodeCoverage.testrunconfig" /searchpathroot:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\Binaries" /resultsfileroot:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\TestResults" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\Nerddinner\myjantest2\Binaries\NerdDinner.Tests.dll" /publish:"http://pheonixdevops01:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" /noprompt /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/2267" /teamproject:"Nerddinner" /platform:"Any CPU" /flavor:"Web.Debug"
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid switch "/publish".
Invalid switch "/publishbuild".
Invalid switch "/teamproject".
Invalid switch "/platform".
Invalid switch "/flavor".
For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"
```

Team Explorer 2013 also installed. I'm trying to run MSTEst in the windows server where VS2013 is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends running the tests in VSTest.Console in later versions than Visual Studio 2010. MSTest  is still available for backwards compatibility with older versions in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013. So Maybe You can try Running the same in [VSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx)

Also there are some errors in your commands like extra quotes:

- /publish:http://pheonixdevops01:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
- /publishbuild:vstfs:///Build/Build/2267

Try Reading:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms182489(v=vs.120).aspx